# Convert a long format data frame into a wide format but keeping the number of columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I didn't see any post solving my problem.

I have a two column data frame. Specifically it has two factors with 11985 and 20200 levels, respectively. The levels of the two two factors are combined to give a total of 849472 observations. Here's an example of the data frame:

```
Category    Gene
BP0000      Fp91000
BP0001      Fp82000
BP0002      Fp70000
BP0010      Fp72000
BP0021      Fp30000
BP0021      Fp30020 
BP0001      Fp30000
BP0000      Fp82000
```

I want to keep in one raw the Category with each factor repeated only one time and in the other column I want in the same cell all the gene that match a category. Here's the format I want:

```
Category    Gene
BP0000      Fp91000 Fp82000
BP0001      Fp82000 Fp30000
BP0002      Fp70000
BP0010      Fp72000
BP0021      Fp30000 Fp30020
```

I've already tried with match but I only get one match of the gene column an there are multiple match's. I'm sorry if this was already post in other question but I didn't see anything like this.

Comment: Maybe `split` will do the trick. It will produce a list, which makes more more sense than storing the result in a data.frame, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(category = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"),
                 value = c("c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df_out <- df %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  mutate(value = paste(value, collapse=" ")) %>%
  unique()
```

Edit: the unique() is very slow with a large data frame. This works much better.

```
df_out <- df %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  mutate(value = paste(value, collapse=" ")) %>%
  group_by(category, value) %>%
  summarise()
```

Comment: It works but it's very slow because the data frame is very large. ¿Do you have any idea of a better option to manipulate the data frame?

Comment: Edited the original post to do the whole operation in dplyr. The unique() was the line slowing it down.

Answer (score 0):

Let `df` be your dataframe.  You might want to try:

```
getme<-function(x){
  r<-paste(df[df$Category==x,]$Gene,collapse = " ")
  return(r)
}

final<-data.frame(cbind(unique(as.character(df$Category)) ,unique(apply(df[1],1,getme))))
names(final)<-c("Category","Gene")
```

`final` is your expected data frame.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the `tidyverse` options using the `tidyr`, `dplyr` and `purrr` packages, you can store Genes as a list-column for each category. This can then be used to manipulate further.

Note: I have saved the Gene and Category as characters rather than factors, which does not seem efficient for such a large dataset.

Store as a list-column, and for convenience I added a count for the number of genes:

```
library(tidyverse)
dataLC <- data %>% 
  tidyr::nest(Gene, .key=GeneListCol) %>% 
  mutate(n_genes = map_int(GeneListCol, ~max(row_number(.$Gene))))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  Category      GeneListCol n_genes
     <chr>           <list>   <int>
1   BP0000 <tibble [2 x 1]>       2
2   BP0001 <tibble [2 x 1]>       2
3   BP0002 <tibble [1 x 1]>       1
4   BP0010 <tibble [1 x 1]>       1
5   BP0021 <tibble [2 x 1]>       2
```

This can be used as is using `purrr` functions, and is probably most useful in this form.

To extract the genes for a selected Category as a vector, which seems like the most useful output, you can do the following:

```
map(dataLC$GeneListCol, "Gene")[dataLC$Category=="BP0001"][[1]]
[1] "Fp82000" "Fp30000"
```

To get a single character string with all the Genes (note this is not really "wide format"), do the following:

```
dataLC %>% 
  mutate(geneList = map_chr(GeneListCol, ~paste(.$Gene, collapse =" "))) %>% 
  select(-GeneListCol)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  Category n_genes        geneList
     <chr>   <int>           <chr>
1   BP0000       2 Fp91000 Fp82000
2   BP0001       2 Fp82000 Fp30000
3   BP0002       1         Fp70000
4   BP0010       1         Fp72000
5   BP0021       2 Fp30000 Fp30020
```

It takes a while to get your head around the list-columns and manipulation with `purrr` map functions, but it can be very useful.  See the tutorial at https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/index.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I've run the first part and store the dataLC as a list-column with the column of counts for the number of genes. But when I run the second command I get the next error:       `Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘select’ for signature ‘"tbl_df"’`

Comment: before running any of this, load `library(tidyverse)`

Comment: otherwise I'm not sure why you would get that error. maybe `select` conflicts with another function in another package. try restarting R session and only load `tidyverse`

Comment: you can avoid the select command with: `dataFinal <- dataLC %>% mutate(geneList = map_chr(GeneListCol, ~paste(.$Gene, collapse =" ")))` and then remove extrac column with `dataFinal[, -2]`